# How to put use a map/lambda inside of a map/lambda in pyspark?

Tags: python, lambda, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a list of lists like this:

```
b = [['r','w'],['n','finished']]
```

I would like to be able to operate on each **element** within each **list**.

I can do this locally in python:

```
result = b.map(lambda aList: \
           map(lambda aString: \
                              '' if aString.strip().lower() in [' finish', 'finished', 'terminate', 'done'] else aString,\
                              aList))
```

But, Spark has trouble serializing the inner `map`:

```
 File "/<path>/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 88, in main
12/11/2015 18:24:49 [launcher]      command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)
12/11/2015 18:24:49 [launcher]    File "//<path>/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 156, in _read_with_length
12/11/2015 18:24:49 [launcher]      return self.loads(obj)
12/11/2015 18:24:49 [launcher]    File "//<path>//python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 405, in loads
12/11/2015 18:24:49 [launcher]      return cPickle.loads(obj)
12/11/2015 18:24:49 [launcher]  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'map'
```

How do I work around this to either, use an inner map or accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

One way to handle this:

```
to_replace = ['finish', 'finished', 'terminate', 'done'] 

rdd = sc.parallelize([['r','w'],['n','finished']])
rdd.map(lambda xs: ['' if  x.strip().lower() in to_replace else x for x in xs])
```

Generally speaking if you find yourself thinking about nested functions it is a good sign you should use a normal function not a lambda expression.

Comment: by "normal function"   you mean `built-ins`?

Comment: Defining a function and use it in map and not using lambda expression. like `def myfunc(x):` and `rdd.map(myfunc)`

Answer (score 2):

Or alternatively and using @zero323's template, if you are using Python 2.x you can use a `map` instead of a `for` but this is a `python` issue not a `pyspark` one, and the effect is the same.

```
to_replace = ['finish', 'finished', 'terminate', 'done'] 

rdd = sc.parallelize([['r','w'],['n','finished']])
rdd.map(
    lambda xs: map(lambda x: "" if x.strip().lower() in to_replace else x, xs)
)
```

But, if `to_replace` list is really big, you should use a [broadcast variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884871/advantage-of-broadcast-variables).