# Spark - Broadcasting HashMap and use it inside Transformations

Tags: apache-spark

Currently inside transformation I am reading one file and creating a HashMap and it is an Static field for re-using purpose.

For each and every record I need to check against the HashMap<> contains the corresponding key or not. If it matches with record key then get the value from HashMap.

What is the best way to do this?

Should i broadcast this HashMap and use it inside Transformation? [`HashMap` or `ConcurrentHashMap`]

Does `Broadcast` will make sure the `HashMap` always contains the value.

Is there any scenario like HashMap become empty and we need to handle that check as well? [ if it's empty load it again ]

**Update:**

Basically i need to use HashMap as a lookup inside transformation. What is the best way to do? Broadcast or static variable?

When i use Static variable for few records i am not getting correct value from HashMap.HashMap contains only 100 elements. But i am comparing this with 25 Million records.

Comment: **"Currently inside transformation I am reading one file and creating a HashMap and it is an Static field for re-using purpose"**. So, are you saying that you are trying to create a broadcast variable for every transformation?! PD. I suggest you to post a small code example, so I can understand better your problem, actually it is a bit obscure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, a `broadcast` variable can be used only for reading purposes, not as a `global` variable, that can be modified in classic programming (one thread, one computer, procedural programming, etc...). Indeed, you can use a global variable in your code and it can be utilized in any part of it (even inside `maps`), but never modified.

As you can see here [Advantages of broadcast variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884871/advantage-of-broadcast-variables), they boost the performance because having a cached copy of the data in all nodes, allow you to avoid transporting repeatedly the same `object` to every node.

> Broadcast variables allow the programmer to keep a read-only variable
>   cached on each machine rather than shipping a copy of it with tasks.

For example.

```py
rdd = sc.parallelize(range(1000))
broadcast = sc.broadcast({"number":1, "value": 4})

rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: x + broadcast.value["value"]) 
rdd.collect()
```

As you can see I access the value inside the dictionary in every iteration of the transformation.

Comment: When i call Broadcast.value inside transformation, will it return the same HashMap or for each row it will create new HashMap?

Comment: I have updated my question with what i am looking exactly..please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You should broadcast the variable. 
Making the variable static will cause the class to be serialized and distributed and you might not want that.